# App Engine Encoding

Tags: python, google-app-engine, encoding

I have some encoding problem on my App Engine/Python application. For example "ô" characters are transformed to "=F4". It's very weird. Even some characters not accented are transformed.
The problem doesn't appear in local but in the app online.

EDIT

Problem solved. The problem was due to a bug on App Engine that give the data as quoted-printable when you include image upload in your form. This comment explains how to fix the issue and includes the appengine_config.py, which makes everything work http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2749#c54

Comment: Please clarify what is your problem. Specify what is your input and output and where both come from.

Comment: For example when I put "Tantum autem cuique" in the form field, "Tantum autem cuiqu=E9" is saved to the database.

Comment: Are you looking at the dev server admin pages? This are known to not display UTF-8 chars.

Comment: Could you send the code? E.g. I need to look at the definition of your html form and the python code that reads the query parameters from the `request`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to encoding. My guess is that you have a form for which the browser will accept encoded data, e.g. characters like "ô". However, on the serve side, when you read this data from the request object, this data is treated like a plain ascii string.

You will need to explicitly tell what format the request data is in to store (or display) it succesfully.